# Apache Camel - Wrong or misunderstanding comportment during type conversion

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

When my body is a list of integer an i try to get the body as Integer i got the first list element i expected to get null, in fact i get null but only when testing

```
from("timer:foo?repeatCount=1")
            .setBody(constant(Arrays.asList(1, 2)))
            .process(e -> System.out.println(e.getIn().getBody(Integer.class)))
            .process(e -> System.out.println(e.getIn().getBody(int.class)));
```

This one will print 1 but if i change the from to some direct and write unit test i will got null don't know if this is an expected behavior because it will cause losing data in some case.

(I use spring boot with camel)

This is how my test route look like

```
public class DemoRouteTest extends CamelTestSupport {

@Override
protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
    return new DemoRoute();
}
```

}

Comment: I don't really get what you are aiming for. You store a list of integers as body on the message contained in the exchange and invoke process for that exchange and ask Camel to return an integer representation of that list. Do you want to perform a split on the list of integers and store each value contained in that list in its own exchange? At least to me, it's a bit unclear

Comment: You're right in fact what is happen here is another dev on my team send a list instead of splitting before then instead of getting an exception we are just getting the first element and losing some data

Comment: @RomanVottner. So my point is why camel representation of list of integer can be just an integer maybe it is volunteer ? And in my case when I run unit test I get null but in production I got the first list element

Comment: My guess is that Camel's [type converter](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/docs/user-manual/modules/ROOT/pages/type-converter.adoc) will attempt to convert the list of integers to a single integer value and return the first value thereof as you explicitely asked for an int type. I.e. you could store arbitrary bytes in the body and later on ask Camel to return it as String value, where the type handler will take care of converting the bytes to a string and so on

Comment: Yeah but I'm quite embarrassing by the fact that is not the same comportment during unit testing (got null value)

Comment: If you look at [SimpleTypeConverter](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/core/camel-support/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/support/SimpleTypeConverter.java#L85), which should be used for base type conversions, it will return null in case of a swallowed exception. It is probably safer to define `Integer.class` instead of `int.class` here anyways. You might start debugging from here on to learn why your unit-tests behaves differently than your production/stage case. My guess would be that you actually have different types in use during test and prod/stage

Comment: @RomanVottner No it is not the case i use camel test support i updated my post with my test class for my point of view is look like is something relating to spring boot but not sure. As you can see my unit test route use the same route definition. But you can run my code by yourself and see what i'm talking about is not related to using int or Integer both produce exactly the same

Comment: @RomanVottner i think i'm right because i finally see this log line Overriding type converter from: StaticMethodTypeConverter: public static java.lang.Integer org.apache.camel.converter.ObjectConverter.toInteger(java.lang.Object) to: org.apache.camel.spring.boot.SpringTypeConverter@619b0c7b

Answer (score 0):

The response when you cast to `int` rather than to `int[]` is always `null`. I made some tweak to the code to demonstrate that. Try to run this snippet on your machine too:

```
from("timer:foo?repeatCount=1")
    .setBody(constant(Arrays.asList(1, 2)))
    .process(e -> {
        System.out.println("Raw body: "+e.getIn().getBody());
        System.out.println("Cast to int[]:");
        int[]body=e.getIn().getBody(int[].class);
        for(int x:body){
            System.out.println(x);
        }
        System.out.println("Cast to int: "+e.getIn().getBody(int.class));
    });
```

You will see the following result:

```
Raw body: [1, 2]
Cast to int[]:
1
2
Cast to int: null
```

Comment: This is not an error this is volunteer for testing my question is about camel comportment for this case I mean by giving me the first list item then I will lost other elements

Comment: You can see that it's producing `null` when cast to `int.class`.

Comment: Also using `direct` component is providing same result, so, not sure why you're getting anything different than `null`.

Comment: No it doesn't product null in 'real' route. read my post that the point if you're running it into unit test it will produce null else you will got the first list element

Comment: Actually I've executed that in a real environment, and either with a `timer` and with a `direct` the result is the one in the answer, I always get a `null`. Could you please run it and see the outcome on your case?

Comment: Of course I can but the code I provided as is already do what I'm describe I just rerun now it print me 1 I may also precise I'm using spring boot

Answer (score 0):

I finally see this log line `Overriding type converter from: StaticMethodTypeConverter: public static java.lang.Integer org.apache.camel.converter.ObjectConverter.toInteger(java.lang.Object) to: org.apache.camel.spring.boot.SpringTypeConverter@619b0c7b` so when camel doesn't able to convert it will use instead SpringTypeConverter of course only when using spring boot framework